# SSH Permission denied (using right password)

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, password

I am having troubles setting an ssh connection between two laptops of mine. I tried different solutions posted on-line, but nothing worked. Since I am pretty new with SSH, I might be missing something important. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on the client, and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on the server.

Here are the steps that I followed:

**On the client**:

- Specified host configuration options in ~/.ssh/config:

  Host [hostname]

  ```
    User [username]
    Hostname [IP address of host]
    ServerAliveInterval 10
  ```
- Generated RSA key by running:

ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -o -a 100

- I supplied a password to ssh-keygen. Private key was saved in ~/.ssh/id_rsa, whereas public key was saved in ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
- I manually copied ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to a USB key.
- At this point, file modes are as follows:

In ~/.ssh:

```
   -rw-rw-r--    config
   -rw-------    id_rsa
   -rw-r--r--    id_rsa.pub
```

**On the server:**

- installed openssh-server;
- created a new file  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys by doing as follows

cat /media/daniele/disk/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

- set file mode of ~/.ssh/authorized_keys to

-rw-rw-r--

- manually edited /etc/ssh/sshd_config to have

in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

**Finally**, on the client, when I try:

```
ssh [username]@[hostname]
```

the server asks for the password

```
[username]@[hostname]'s password:
```

but, even if I enter the correct one, the server does not accept it:

```
Permission denied, please try again
```

and, after three attempts, it closes the connection. Please find [here](https://pastebin.com/RrGaSJHE) a more descriptive output I get by using

```
ssh -v -v -v [username]@[hostname]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: IIRC the `authorized_keys` file should be `-rw-------` (octal mode `600`) and the `~/.ssh` directories themselves should be `drwx------` (octal mode `700`) on both client and server

Comment: Thank you @steeldriver, but that did not work

Comment: Just to be clear, are you entering your Unix pass*word* for the remote account, or the pass*phrase* that you entered when generating the keypair? Is your home directory on the remote host encrypted?

Comment: Good point. I am entering the __passphrase__ entered when generating the keypair. Concerning my home directory on the remote host, I did: `ls -a /home` and found no `.encryptfs` folder, so I assume it is not encrypted. Am I correct? Sorry for the stupid question, but am I supposed to run some combination of adduser/passwd on the host?

Comment: If that helps, entering any other random combination of characters, always returns `Permission denied, please try again`. I just tried

Comment: Probably the easiest thing to try is enter your Unix pass**word** when you get the `[username]@[hostname]'s password:` prompt (at that point, key-based authentication has already been tried and rejected) and then open a second terminal window on your client and try to connect again. (The first - password based - login will decrypt and mount your home dir, **if** that is the issue.)

Comment: @steeldriver that did not work either, but thanks for the hint

Comment: At what point did it not work? Did the password-based login fail as well? At this point I don't really know what to suggest except starting over and using `ssh-copy-id` instead of transferring the key manually.

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, the password-based login initially failed as well. However, following your hints, I added a new user `[username]` on the _host_ and tried the corresponding Unix pass**word** when I got `[username]@[hostname]'s password`, and that **did work**. However, now my (newbie) question is whether I am bypassing the RSA key or not

Comment: Not exactly "bypassing" - based on your log, it is *trying* the key but failing and dropping back to password-based authentication. The prompt will be different for unlocking your RSA key (something like `Enter passphrase for key '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa': `). *Having logged in with your password, are you **then** able to log in from another terminal using your keypair?*

Comment: @steeldriver Sorry for keeping you waiting, but I did few different attempts. Anyway, no, having logged in with my password, I am not then able to log in from another terminal using my keypair. It keeps asking for the Unix pass**word**. However, I believe the key is being checked somehow, because if I do `ssh [other user]@[hostname]` I get this warning: `Agent admitted failure using the key` (note: [other user] is the default `home` user I have on `[hostname]`). Does it make sense?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the hostname of the server, try using the ip-adres.
I ran into the same problem when setting up my server and this seemed to resolve the problem.

`ssh [username]@[host_ip-adres]`

If you want to use the hostname you might need to set up a dns-server.
but you can do without.

Comment: Thank you @Bjorn, but it did not work

Comment: the authorized keys are user specific, if you did not make the directory in the home folder of the user you want to remotely connect to the rsa key will not be found

Comment: Logged in to upvote you my man!

Answer (score 1):

You should decide whether you want connection authentication by key/id or by password then focus on that to find the issue.  I recommend using key/id since *when managed correctly, it is the more secure method*.

SSH will always fall back to asking for a password even in cases where it will never work.  To avoid this use **`-o 'batchmode yes'`** (these quotes are needed) on the client ssh command making the connection.  Then if the key cannot be accepted, it bypasses the password prompt (this is normally for use of ssh in a script that needs to avoid getting stuck at the password prompt).  SSH will only try 3 keys at one time, so if the valid key is the 4th, it will not be tried and the connection will be aborted.  It is best to try only one key per connection attempt if you are certain that it is the correct one.  Then you can repeat the connection attempts while making changes at the server.  It will help to have log file information from the server.  Do **`grep sshd /var/log/auth.log`** to see what sshd is trying to tell you.

Comment: set all file modes to the most secure, 0600 (`-rw-------`) for regular files, 0700 (`drwx------`) for directories.  you have no reason to allow anyone else to read these.

Comment: your comment about the logs helped me find the issue: My shell as misconfigured so it was declining the ssh session. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You may try adding your user to the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
...
AllowUsers ... <username>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define Host with `Host [hostname]` you have to use `ssh [hostname]`

Permission is denieed because you're not actually using the keyfile when `ssh [user]@[hostname]`

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't load your private key (the one without .pub) into the ssh-agent then you need to specify it in your ssh connection.

```
SSH -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@host
```

It looks like it isn't asking you for your ssh key pass, but your user pass which is why your password is failing